# 'The installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory' Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, python, mysql

I am trying to install the MySQL connector for python but I get the error

> The installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory 
>   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\mysql

This is while we I am running as administrator

Comment: You are not supposed to have ownership of that directory.  You will have to install the normal version of Python that isn’t from the Windows Store.

Comment: [Official Python releases for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) (Non-Microsoft Store versions).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the connector using the command prompt:

```
python -m pip install mysqlclient
python -m pip install mysql-connector-python
python -m pip install pymysql
```